# How to download old Java please

Tags: java

My daughter is starting A Level  Computer Science this Sept and hopes to study a MOOC course on Java over the summer. We have this.

We have quite an old computer : Windows XP 2002.
I'm struggling to find online how do download Java and where to get it.

Any advice very welcome. (Buying new computer not possible. )

Many thanks
Gemma

Comment: See here : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [link provided by @Arnaud](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) to download Java8, [which is officially unsupported on Windows XP but will run just fine](https://superuser.com/questions/1169983/is-java-8-supported-on-windows-xp). Make sure to download the JDK (Java Development Kit - used to make programs from code) and not just the JRE (Java Runtime Environment - used to run Java programs). The JDK includes the JRE, so running your programs will not be an issue.

I would recommend installing an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) which will greatly increase programming productivity.

I would also recommend installing another OS on the machine, like Linux Mint or (K)Ubuntu, if you have the know-how or know someone who can do this for you and the laptop is to be used exclusively for programming and browsing.

Answer (score 5):

**Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP!**

So I recommend not using Windows XP (you have a great increased chance to get virusses and get hacked etc.)

See here: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml and here https://superuser.com/a/1169990

**Install Linux with Java**

I recommend installing Linux on the machine, and then install the Java version that is supported. For 32 bit version, see here: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

**Or, Run online**

Or, you could run java somewhere online. See for example here:

https://jaxenter.com/top-6-java-compilers-students-141549.html 
([codiva.io](https://www.codiva.io/), [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/%20JDoodle), etc)